# What is Webs.com/1.0 Webserver?

Tags: apache, http, server, http-headers, connection

Ok, So I am checking if a certain website is running apache... The problem is when I make an HTTP request and receive the HTTP Response Header it says that the web server is running `Webs.com/1.0`, what does this mean?